# How does the factory design pattern make it robust and loosly coupled in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I recently got a book from amazon.in named java design patterns. Now i am reading factory design pattern. I could not get what is loose coupling please help me. explain me in an easy way. give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface Iscan {
void scan();
}

public EyeScannerClass implements Iscan{
 void scan(){
System.out.println("Some Person's eye scanned...")
}

public BarcodeScannerClass implements Iscan{
System.out.println("A produc's barcode from supermarket scanned...")
}

public ScannerFactory{

public static Iscan createScanner(){
//here you can choose which scanner to create by the help of polymorphism because different scanner classes implementing same scanner interface
}

}

public SomeBusinessLogicClass {

public void someMethod(){
//if the scanner impl changes you do not need to change your business logic. all change must be done in factory and the other users of that factory is not affected.
Iscan scanner=ScannerFactory.createScanner();

}

}
```

I tried to explain why it is useful using factory design pattern above. we have an interface and two implementers of that interface and a factory class which is creating scanners and a client using that factory. if sth changes at the scanner impl the client do not need to change anything. With this approach we provide loose coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below code(1)

```
Class Vehicle{

int modelYear=2010;

Engine engine=new Engine(); //Engine object

}
```

Now consider this(2)

```
Class Vehicle{

int modelYear;

Engine engine;

Vehicle(int modelYear,Engine engine)
{
this.modelYear=modelYear;
this.engine=engine;
}
```

In case 1 The Vehicle class is depending on the Engine class to create Engine object means more dependency i.e tight coupling

In case 2 we are creating Engine object else where(Container) and passing the object via constructor or setter method. means less dependency i.e loose coupling.

Factory Design Pattern talks about the same thing,to decrease the dependency between 2 classes create objects elsewhere and pass them via constructors or setter methods.

Whole spring framework is based on this,i.e loose coupling where IOC container creates the objects when needed, and injects them to the respective destination(Dependency Injection)

Comment: sorry man, i could not. case 2 spring creates object in 1 java compiler crates object. so how do we get loose coupling?